# Need help with the past perfect in this sentence

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-perfect

I stumbled upon this sentence and got confused:
“ ***Actually, your cartoon was the last show he had seen before getting arrested.***”
Does it sound natural? And if so, can you explain why the past perfect is used here? The past perfect indicates something that happened before some events in the past. He had seen the cartoon before his arrest. But why this part “your cartoon was” in the past simple then?

Comment: As people have often commented on these forums, it isn't necessary to use a perfect tense for _every_ verb if the meaning is clear, and it would make the sentence unduly complicated if you did.